# Gdal_translate with WMS troubles

Tags: python, wms, gdal-translate

The data I'm interested in is found here and can be opened directly in your browser:

http://maps.greenmin.gl/geusmap/ows/32624.jsp?nocache=nocache&whoami=[email]&LAYERS=grl_geus_500k_geology_map&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&STYLES=&SRS=EPSG%3A32624&BBOX=499980.0,7190220.0,609780.0,7400040.0&WIDTH=1500&HEIGHT=3000

Then I'm using this code in my terminal to output it to a GTiff with its reference system intact, which is based on information found [here](https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/gdal-dev/2013-April/035951.html).

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff -co "TFW=YES" "http://maps.greenmin.gl/geusmap/ows/32624.jsp?nocache=nocache&whoami=130.225.0.251&LAYERS=grl_geus_500k_geology_map&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&STYLES=&SRS=EPSG%3A32624&BBOX=499980.0,7190220.0,609780.0,7400040.0&WIDTH=1500&HEIGHT=3000" output_geo.tif
```

I then get an error

```
Input file size is 561895206, 1073741824
0ERROR 3: Free disk space available is 745445371904 bytes, whereas 2413321533549182976 are at least necessary. You can disable this check by defining the CHECK_DISK_FREE_SPACE configuration option to FALSE.
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why not just request the layer as Tiff, as it is a supported image format for this service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else may stumble on this problem.

I managed to get workarounds to it, but it produced a file size of 92 gb. Which made it unusable. I went with a solution of opening it in QGIS. Then I exported it which can be done by either:

1) Right clicking the layer and saving it as.

2) Using the print composer function or

3) Download the Georefexporter plugin which is available for the Linux version of QGIS.

However my problem is the WMS service wont give images any larger than 3000 pixels. So I had to settle for a smaller 1500x3000 image which unfortunately is pix-elated for my purpose. But it is usable.